# What does assignment into a right shift mean in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, bit-shift

I've come across some puzzling code:

```
int mask = someFunction();
mask>>=1; // What does this line do?
```

I've never seen this pattern before and would like to understand what it is doing.

Comment: It's not "assignment into a right shift". See `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, etc. This is very high on the list of things you should be able to solve yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: This shouldn't have a close-vote as not constructive.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never seen this in years of working with C++ although += etc. are very common, using it with operator >> is a new one for me.  I think it is because >> is two characters that I didn't match it to all the +=, -=, *=, etc.

Comment: @WilliamKF [Here you go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same as `mask = mask >> 1`.  Works same as all the usual operators with `=`.

Comment: Except that `mask` is only evaluated once (which makes no difference in this case, but could of `mask` is a more complicated (lvalue) expression).